# multiple initialization of the same object in python

Tags: python, class, oop, initialization

I have several noobie questions related to multiple initialization of the same class instance in python. Is it proper way to change attributes of the object by creating instance many times:

```
obj=MyClass(a,b)
obj=MyClass(c,d)
obj=MyClass(e,f)
```

Are commands `obj=MyClass(a,b)` and `obj.__init__(a,b)` equal? If not, what is the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example you're instantiating three different objects of class `MyClass` and discarding the first two. In order to be able to perform the same initialization several times on the same object I'd define an `initialize(self)` method in `MyClass` and call it from `__init__(self)`.

Answer (score 1):

`obj = MyClass(a,b)` - this will create a new instance

`obj.__init__(a,b)` - this will call `__init__` method with on the current instance

Usually you call `__init__` implicit once, when creating an instance (`obj = MyClass(a,b)`) and modify it's fields later directly or using some methods. Like:

```
obj = MyClass(a,b)
obj.a = 'foo'
obj.b = 2
```

Comment: obj=MyClass(a,b) calls the function '__init__' What else does this do?

Comment: @freude allocate memory for a new instance

Comment: @Nicola Musatti, ok, I see. Is there difference even if all my attributes are defined inside the function init?

Comment: Yes, there is, because they're all referring to `self`, which is different in each of your example's calls.